# Python: Omit single type from Union type

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

Is it possible to create a new Union Type which is basically the same as another but without a single type. Instead of writing this:

```py
NUMBER_T = Union[int, float, Decimal]  # or even int | float | Decimal
DECIMAL_T = Union[float, Decimal]
```

I want to write something like this:

```py
NUMBER_T = Union[int, float, Decimal]
DECIMAL_T = Omit[NUMBER_T, int]  # or even something like NUMBER_T ^ int
```

This is possible [in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys). Is it also possible in Python?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible as type hints are not inherent part of the lang but an addition added later (variable annotations theoretically can be anything and not type hints, their usage as type hints was another PEP and that's how it now goes). If you can modify the code of NUMBER_T, just do it the other way around, `NUMBER_T = Union[DECIMAL_T, int]`

Comment: from typing import TypeVar, Union

T = TypeVar('T')

def omit_type(union_type: Union[T, ...], type_to_exclude: type) -> Union[T, ...]:
    return Union[t for t in union_type.__args__ if t != type_to_exclude]

NUMBER_T = Union[int, float, Decimal]

# Create a new Union type by excluding a type
DECIMAL_T = omit_type(NUMBER_T, int)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer does this code work? AFAIK `...` is not allowed here and mypy, pyre and pyright throw many errors and ruff doesn't recognize any type violations.